# Plotting over the unit interval $[0,1]$

Tags: plotting

Related to the question : [Neumann and Dirichlet eigenvalue problem - Eigenfunctions on the square](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/118529/neumann-and-dirichlet-eigenvalue-problem-eigenfunctions-on-the-square)

I'd like to do the same thing on the line instead of the rectangle, i.e. with $\sin(k\,π\,x)$ and $\cos(k\,π\,x)$. How could I do that? I have obtained the following result, but I don't know how to improve it :

```
Clear[ψN];
ψN[j_][x_] := Cos[j Pi x];

Plot[ψN[3][x], {x} ∈ Line[{0, 1}], 
  PlotPoints -> 100, AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: Change `{x} ∈ Line[{0, 1}]`  to `{x, 0, 1}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to substitute `Interval` for `Line`. `Interval` is the 1D equivalent for 2D `Line`.

```
ψN[j_][x_] := Cos[j Pi x];
Plot[ψN[2][x], x ∈ Interval[{0, 1}]]
```

[image: plot]